If two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be such that $a_n>b_n$ then show that $\lim a_n\ge\lim b_n$
$$ \text{Take two converging sequences } \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \text{ and } \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty, \text{ such that } a_n > b_n \text{ for all } n. \text{ Show that } \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n. \text{ Can we replace the weak inequality with strict inequality?} $$
Here is my approach to this proof...and I have the following questions

Is my proof correct?
Is there a better way to prove this?

My proof
Let $$\{a_n\} \rightarrow a \quad and \quad \{b_n\} \rightarrow b$$
Then by definition of convergence we have,
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \;N_a \; and \; N_b \in \mathbb{N} \;such \;that  $$
\begin{equation} 
a-\epsilon < a_n < a+\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge N_a \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b-\epsilon < b_n < b+\epsilon \quad \forall n\ge N_b \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, let us assume that $$b>a$$
which implies $$b - \epsilon > a - \epsilon \quad and \quad b + \epsilon > a + \epsilon \tag{3} $$
We also have that, $$a_n > b_b$$
Now from (1) and (2) we can say that
$$
a_n > b_n \quad 
\text{and} \quad b_n > b - \epsilon \\
\Rightarrow a_n > b - \epsilon \\ \text{and}\\
a_n < a + \epsilon < b + \epsilon \quad [\text{from (3)}] \\
\text{Therefore, we have for all}\quad \epsilon \ge 0 \quad \exists N = \max\{N_a,N_b\} \quad\text{such that}\\ b - \epsilon < a_n < b + \epsilon \quad\forall n \ge N \\ \Rightarrow \quad \{a_n\} \rightarrow b \\ \Rightarrow a = b \quad \text{[Since, two distinct sequences can't converge to more than one point.]}
$$
But, this contradicts our assumption that b > a, so our supposition was wrong and b must be less than or equal to a.
Moreover we cant repla]ce the weak inequality with strict inequality because we can come up with a sequences $$\{a_n\} \rightarrow a \quad \text{and}\quad \{b_n\}\rightarrow b$$ such that $$a = b$$
One such example is
$$ \{a_n\} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1 \\
\{b_n\} = 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow 1 \\
\text{and}\quad a_n > b_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
Also, this is my first time asking a question in math stack exchange so any tip/advice on the way I've presented my question is welcome.
Thank you.

@hff1 Could you please elaborate on why I can't conclude $b - \epsilon$ ?
doesn't it follow from the following statement?
$$
a_n > b_n > b - \epsilon \quad \forall n > \text{Some Natural number}\quad \mathbb{N}
$$

Although your hint(the proof idea) does seem more intuitive now that i think about it.
Thank you.

A similar proof is to consider at the beginning the case $b_n=0$. You will have $a_n >0$ and if $a<0$ can you find a contradiction? Finally, you apply this result to $a_n - b_n$ for the general case.

Here is my approach, which is not too dissimilar to OP's, although maybe I present it differently. I'm sure it can be shortened or improved upon.
Suppose $a_n\to a\in\mathbb{R};\ b_n\to b\in\mathbb{R};\ a_n>b_n\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$
Suppose by way of contradiction, that $b>a.$ Define $\varepsilon:= \frac{b-a}{2},$ and note that $\varepsilon>0.$
Since $b_n\to b,\ \exists\ N$ such that $\vert b-b_n\vert <\varepsilon\ \forall\ n\geq N.$
Thus for all $n\geq N:$

If $b_n\geq b,$ then since $b>a+\varepsilon,\ $ (by sort-of transitivity of $>),\quad b_n>a+\varepsilon$ also.

If $b_n< b,$ then $b_n-b<0,\ $ which implies that $\vert b-b_n\vert = b-b_n < \varepsilon=\frac{b-a}{2},\implies b_n > a+ \varepsilon.$


Either way, we have that $b_n > a+ \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N.$ Furthermore, since $a_n\to a,\ \exists\ N'\ $ such that $\vert a-a_n\vert <\varepsilon\ \forall\ n\geq N'.$ Define $N^*:=\max\{N,N'\}.$ Similar reasoning to above tells us that $a_n < a + \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N'.$
Since $a_n < a+ \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N',$ and $N^*\geq N',$ it follows that $a_n < a+ \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N^*.$ Since $b_n > a+ \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N,$ and $N^*\geq N,$ it follows that $b_n > a+ \varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N^*.$ This implies, $b_n>a+ \varepsilon>a_n$ for all $n\geq N^*.$
This contradicts the fact that $a_n>b_n\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$
